# Resize a bitmap to a thumbnail size flex

Tags: image, apache-flex, resize, runtime

I would like to resize my images to a thumbnail size at runtime when assigning them to an item renderer  in flex.
How can i accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have the images in memory? If so, you can just set the height and width of the image component in your item renderer, it should scale the image for you. 
It may be more efficient to pre generate cached thumbnails on the server of your images and use those for both speed and image quality.